# Can one Azure Mobile Apps service be used for an Android and iOS app?

Tags: azure, mobile, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to develop an app using Xamarin for Android and iOS. I also want to use the [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) service. Do I need to pay for two Mobile Apps service plans or can one be used for both, the Android and iOS version of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't need to** pay for two Mobile Apps service plans for Android and iOS project. iOS app and Android app can share those resources in backend.

In the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service-mobile%2ftoc.json) it says:

> In App Service, an app runs in an App Service plan. An App Service
>   plan defines a set of compute resources for a web app to run. These
>   compute resources are analogous to the server farm in conventional web
>   hosting. **One or more apps can be configured to run on the same
>   computing resources (or in the same App Service plan).**

For Xamarin.Forms apps: [app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started)

For Xamarin.iOS apps:[app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started)

For Xamarin.Android apps: [app-service-mobile-xamarin-android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using it as a backend, so you can have one app service plan for both, android and iOS.

When connecting to the backend, depending on how you abstracted this layer(with Xamarin, with mvvmcross for example or xamarin forms), you would have to use just dedicated client sdk.